# ASP.NET/SQL Function not storing all values in a loop

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

So I'm creating a monopoly game, and I've got two functions which read/write information about the game to/from a database so it can be retrieved between postbacks. I also have a start game function which initialises everything to 0 and then calls the writeToDatabase(). createArrays() just creates a list of players/squares, squares have been removed as they'not relevant.

The problem I'm having is I believe it is only storing some of the values within the loop. When the start game function is called it correctly sets the  players positions to  0, and their money to 1500, however for some reason when reading from the database again the 4th players details immediately go back to what they were during the previous session.

```
        private void readFromDatabase()
        {
            createArrays();

            for (int i = 0; i < players.Count(); i++)
            {
                players[i].SetID(Convert.ToInt32(players_table.GetRow(i)["ID"]));
                players[i].SetPosition(Convert.ToInt32(players_table.GetRow(i)["position"]));
                players[i].SetMoney(Convert.ToInt32(players_table.GetRow(i)["money"]));
                players[i].SetInJail(Convert.ToBoolean(players_table.GetRow(i)["isInJail"]));
                players[i].SetIsBankrupt(Convert.ToBoolean(players_table.GetRow(i)["isBankrupt"]));
            }

            currentPlayerID = Convert.ToInt32(gameinfo_table.GetRow(0)["CurrentPlayerID"]);
            currentSquareID = Convert.ToInt32(gameinfo_table.GetRow(0)["CurrentSquareID"]);
            freeParkingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(gameinfo_table.GetRow(0)["FreeParkingAmount"]);

            currentPlayer = players[currentPlayerID];
            CurrentSquare = squares[currentSquareID];
        }

        private void writeToDatabase()
        {
            CurrentSquare = squares[currentSquareID];

            for (int i = 0; i < players.Count(); i++)
            {
                SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow prow = players_table.GetRow(players[i].GetID());

                prow["ID"] = players[i].GetID().ToString();
                prow["position"] = players[i].GetPosition().ToString();
                prow["money"] = players[i].GetMoney().ToString();
                prow["isInJail"] = players[i].IsInJail().ToString();
                prow["isBankrupt"] = players[i].IsBankrupt().ToString();

                players_table.Update(prow);
            }

            SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow girow = gameinfo_table.GetRow(0);

            girow["CurrentPlayerID"] = currentPlayerID.ToString();
            girow["CurrentSquareID"] = CurrentSquare.GetID().ToString();
            girow["FreeParkingAmount"] = freeParkingAmount.ToString();

            gameinfo_table.Update(girow);
        }

        private void startGame()
        {
            createArrays();
            currentPlayerID = 0;
            currentPlayer = players[0];
            CurrentSquare = squares[0];
            writeToDatabase();
        }

        private void createArrays()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Player player = new Player(i);
                players.Add(player);
            }
        }
```

I really can't work out why this is happening, as when it creates the player array it loops through 4 times, therefore creating 4 brand new players, and immediately overwriting the details in the database. It just seems odd it works perfectly fine for the first 3 players but the 4ths details don't seem to change. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure it something simple but I have spent hours on this and haven't got anywhere.

Comment: I have also tried reducing the players to 3 and the issue still arises. It just seems to be with the last player in the array not setting properly.

Comment: With `players_table.GetRow(players[i].GetID() + 1)`, are you sure you get the correct row to update? Did you debug and verify?

Comment: The debugger is your friend here. Put breakpoints in the readFromDatabase and writeToDatabase and look at what your code is doing and what values are present in your variables. Also there is a lot of code from your GetRow and Update that could be the cause here

Comment: OT executing `players_table.GetRow(i)` 5 times may be a bit wasteful - get that row once and read from there

Comment: Ah, the + 1 wasn't supposed to be there, the issue I've described is without it. I'll update the code

Comment: I really would like to see that GetRow method. Are you searching a collection of rows using the ID or do you just need to read the rows one by one?

Comment: I believe each row of the database is added to a list, and the GetRow just finds the item in the list with that index. I did not write the functions associated with the database, and they work perfectly fine in the other project.

Comment: I also stepped through the code with the debugger, and at the very end of the write to database function all the values are correct, it is just when reading from the database again the wrong values are retrieved for the last player.